# The same figure prints on two consecutive pages

Tags: output-formatting, printing

I have a Mathematica 13 notebook that includes some illustrations that repeat across pages when the document is printed. The figure is not duplicated in the notebook - there are not two figure cells that contain the same image.

A screenshot of the **Print Preview** is shown below. The same image appears in the **Print Preview** at the bottom on Page 4 and at the top of Page 5.

I have also noticed that Code cells will not break across consecutive pages.

[image: Figure is duplicating across pages]

My questions are:

- Are there any properties for a `Figure` cell that can be applied to keep the same figure from duplicating on consecutive pages?
- Are there any `Code` cell properties that will allow a code cell to break across pages?

Comment: It is very difficult to troubleshoot a code problem *in the abstract*, blind, without an example. Perhaps if you shared the file somebody might take a look, although be aware that notebooks are executable files and I tend not to open notebooks from unknown sources.